# 3D Animations in XNA 3.1

Tags: xna, c#, animation, models, xna3.1

Well, guys. I'm in a Game Design class at school. Before you ask "WHY ARE YOU USING 3.1 INSTEAD OF 4" -- I would like to point out that C# 2008, and .NET framework 3 is NOT my preferred environment, nor is Blender 2.49.

I have gotten a pretty decent grip on Blender so far, I think. At least, for what I've figured out how to do. ( Applying textures, exporting to .fbx, and bone-weights ).

Now, I've seen various mentions of using "Skinned Models" in xna 4.0, and I've noticed that 3.1 has no such distinction, so I assume anything you do in 4 with skinned models means alternative methods in 3.1. I have also found nearly NO documentation on 3.1. All of them seem to have actually been updated to cover 4.0 ( Seriously, since when do people update their outdated tutorials? ;_; )

I'm asking around to see if there's any way to play animations stored in .fbx files ( if so, how to do it ), so that I don't waste my time understanding the animations and what not in Blender. ( Or better yet, is there something else that I SHOULD be doing instead? )

If it's not achievable, then I can obviously just use a bunch of constants or some work-around system to apply bone transformations, but it would be really nice if I didn't need to do that.

Some other things -
I've noticed that ALL models I load seem to have semi-transparent textures. Can anybody offer an immediate explanation for this? To see what I'm talking about, [here's a video.](http://youtu.be/BVVZqcjuT3Y?t=22s)

Also, could somebody give me advice as far as loading an environment and multiple models?
I think I would use the same camera and projection matrix, and then simply give a new "World" matrix to all of the items, but for some reason, I don't think that's quite right. I read somewhere that the purpose of the Matrix type was to avoid storing position information for every individual model, and store it collectively instead. ( Which, makes sense, really. Especially when some games probably load a gajillion models x3 Vector3's. That could add up fairly quickly, I'm sure. )

I know this is fairly generic / vague, but since I haven't written any code with bugs, I can't exactly ask specific questions, I guess.

If you have a resource that is still rele

Comment: You'll find vs 3.1 at the bottom: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I can't believe I hadn't seen that one.